# how to restore the display setting?

Tags: 15.04, display

All the icons n window is maximize n all the setting is correct an all the text and all the window are maximize when open.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can reset nautilus by deleting its config file.

First backup config:

```
$ mv ~/.config/nautilus ~/.config/nautilus_old
$ mv ~/.gconf/apps/nautilus ~/.gconf/apps/nautilus_old
```

Then reeboot and if it works then you can delete the backup files.
Otherwise just copy them back to restore the current state.